# c# illegal character in file path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, path

Hey guys I have this piece of code that will first store a path in a variable, check if that path exists, if not create it. then take that path and add my file name to it.

Here is the code

```
appData = string.Format("{0}{1}\"", controller.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

if (!Directory.Exists(appData))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appData);

filePath = string.Format("{0}\"{1}", appData, model.File.FileName);
model.File.SaveAs(filePath);
data.Add("attachment", filePath);
```

But when it gets to the SaveAs function it states

```
Illegal character in path
```

> AppDath = C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Team Foundation Server\Team
>   Projects\Shared\Orchard
>   1.6\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\App_Data\392216b5-32ad-41f4-82bf-e074b13f25df\"

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
filePath = Path.Combine(appData, model.File.FileName);
```

same to create `appData` path

```
appData = Path.Combine(controller.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Comment: I fixed my appData variable like so "appData = string.Format("{0}{1}", controller.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());" and then my filePath worked :)

Comment: @Canvas A better practice would just be to not use String.Format to combine paths... when you have a dedicated method ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
filePath = string.Format(@"{0}\"{1}", appData, model.File.FileName);
```

The `@` char show the compiler that the string doesn't have any backslashed characters.
Normaly, you use the `\` prefix in some special chars, like `\n` means a newline. You string has a `\`, so the compiler tries to resolve it with the next char in the string.

Another way is to escape the backslash with the second one, like this:

```
filePath = string.Format(@"{0}\\"{1}", appData, model.File.FileName);
```

Comment: It breaks when trying to create the appData location